# how to identity if button submit has opened a new browser window or new tab in watin

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, watin

I have the same problem, my site opens a new tab whenever I click on the submit form button.
Is there any way to check whether i have opened a new tab or new windows in watin

I have tried myself with ie.internetexplorers to get the new url, it worked in some cases but in most cases it failed.

does any one have any better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Browser.AttachTo()` should find you the new window:

```
 string expectedUrl = "http://mysite.com/expected-url/";

 using (var newWindow = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(
                  Find.ByTitle("Expected title")))
 {
       Assert.AreEqual(expectedUrl, newWindow.Url);
 }
```